# Hibernate/JPA one-to-one relationship

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, database-design, architecture

I have two entities - `Request` and `Report`. Each `Request` can have only one `Report` and each `Report` can belong to only one `Request`. This is  one-to-one relationship.

Right now I'm thinking about underlying database schema. Right now in table `requests` I have `FK` to `PK reports.id`.

Is it a correct approach ? Where `FK` to other entity must be placed - in `reports` or `requests` table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's all you need regarding the foreign keys. You may want to also add a unique constraint (unique index) to the foreign key for better performance and consistency guarantees.